# UISegmentedControl under IOS 13

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

Under IOS 13, it appears it is not possible to change the background or tintcolor of segmented controls programmatically.  My app that was operating correctly with a blue blackground and white tintcolor now appears in white/gray background and black tintcolor.  The code to change the colors is executing and there are no errors.

Anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Using objective-C, have a tableview with an array of  data elements consisting of Labeled segmented controls.

Set Value ...............YES   NO

I can change the color of the Label element using

```
[ee setLabelColor:[UIColor blueColor];
```

but I can not figure out how to change the Segmented Control background or text color.  Do I need to use attributes on the NSMutableDictionary?

```
    NSMutableDictionary *dd = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    DataElement *ee;
    ee  = [[DataElement alloc] initSegmentedControlWithLabel:@"Set Value" defaultValue:[s intValue] items:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"No", @"Yes", nil]];

[ee setTextColor;[UIColor blueColor]];


    [dd setObject:ee forKey:@"dataElement"];
    [dd setObject:@"Set-Value" forKey:@"type"];
    [aSpecific addObject:dd];
```

The tableview appears with the labels but the segmented control has the YES and NO in white/off white backgrounds.

Comment: Please show how _you_ are doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 13, The the way to change the tint color (tinting both titles and images) is to call the segmented control's `setTitleTextAttributes(_:for:)` with a different `.foregroundColor`.

Comment: Updated actual code above.  The segmentedControl is within a data element.